# Google Developer Team Account - Is it possible

Tags: android, google-play, account

I work in a team which is writing an android app. This app will NOT be distributed via the Google Play store.

I want the app to use notifications, so I need to register an app. 
I can create a Google developer account for me personally to do this. However I want other members of the team to access this. How do I do this?

The only option I see is to create a google play developers account, but I have no need of the google play store.

Does any one know how to do this.

Comment: Use the store but make it invite-only beta access. You'll get all the features of the play store (updating, notifications, etc) and it will only be visible to your team.

Comment: Hi Hobo Joe, I don't think I am explaining this very clearly. I have a google account on https://developers.google.com. Through this i can register an application at this address https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android . I can then add GCM as a service to it. However this is all under my login. I work as part of a team, and I want all the developers to be able to access this information. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**In terms of usage**

If you want to allow to use that app only to your group members then you can publish that app in closed alpha testing section where you have to give testing access to limited members by adding there email to the console. so that only those people will be able to use the app whose email have given tester access.

**In terms of development**

You can give access permission to your developers gmail accounts from google play apps publishing console settings so that they are able to upload and publish app from there account too. There is hierarchy of settings through which you can control up to what level they can make changes too this account with their given access.

Comment: Hi indramurari, I do not want to publish tot he google play store. But if I want a team account is this the only way?

Comment: @rideintothesun It's not the only way but then you will have to build your own system which will be able to get the apk updates and team members should be able to access the apk from that source. i.e. it should work like playstore. But why should we build the other system if we already have one